# Creating two lists from one to get IDs and numerical values

Tags: python, list

I have a list e.g. below

```
Final_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',  'B_-1', 'C_-1', 'D_-1']
```

and I would like to create two lists to get IDs and then numerical values. 
To do that, I have split after "_" the following to split;

```
j = []    
for i in Final_list:
    timelags = i.split("_")
    j.append(timelags)
print(j)
```

and the result is

```
List_2 = [['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['D'], ['E'], ['B', '-1'], ['C', '-1'], ['D', '-1']]
```

But I would like to create two lists e.g. see below;

```
ID = ['A','B','C','D','E']
Timelag = [[0],[-1,0],[-1,0],[-1,0],[0]]
```

You can see that there are no duplicates in the ID list and Timelag list has 0 if there is no _ is the original list e.g. for A and E.
P.S: the order needs to be the same for both lists.

Comment: You are using split() which returns a list

Comment: what does `0` mean in such sublist `[-1,0]` ?

Comment: do you need to keep order, or just order between the lists? do you need sorted sublists in timelags?

Comment: 0 means e.g. in List_2 for A there is no "_"  and some numerical value.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Order is important, e.g. the first items of both ID and  Timelag lists corresponds to each other

Comment: But for B there is an `_`, then shouldn't it be just `[-1]` instead of `[-1, 0]`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: `0` mean current values and `-1` mean one step previous values.

Comment: @yklsga: `B` also has entry without _ as well and that is why it has `-1` and `0`

Comment: got it, I missed it@Muhammad

Comment: Why negative vote :( ? Is not the question interesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If items in each lists must correspond to each other, you could map each element to a value:

```
Final_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',  'B_-1', 'C_-1', 'D_-1']

mapping = {}
for elt in Final_list:
    if len(elt) == 1:
        mapping[elt] = [0]
    else:
        mapping[elt[0]] = [int(elt[2:])] + mapping[elt[0]]

mapping

{'A': [0], 'B': [-1, 0], 'C': [-1, 0], 'D': [-1, 0], 'E': [0]}
```

It does not preserve the order of the elements, but the pairing of elements and their value remains intact.

If lists are important, they can be extracted - they maintain the pairing, but not the order:

```
list(mapping.keys()), list(mapping.values())

(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [[0], [-1, 0], [-1, 0], [-1, 0], [0]])
```

Further, an ordered dictionary could be used to maintain both pairing, and order of the lists, depending on the importance this has to your use case.

Caveat: the tokenization of the input data is rather crude and assumes that length, and values of the data is constrained. Refinements can be added depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby` Solution

```
from itertools import groupby
l = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(Final_list),lambda x:x[0])]
d = [(i[0], [i[1].split('_')[1],0] if len(i)==2 else [0]) for i in l]
list(zip(*d))
```

Output:

```
[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), ([0], ['-1', 0], ['-1', 0], ['-1', 0], [0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **order is to be preserved**, use `OrderedDict`. Store the `key` and then its `timestamp` in it and use it to build your list.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> for x in Final_list: 
        if len(x)<=1 : 
            d[x] = 0 
        else : 
            a, b = x.split('_') 
            d[a] = b 

>>> d
=> OrderedDict([('A', 0), ('B', '-1'), ('C', '-1'), ('D', '-1'), ('E', 0)])

    #convert into the format OP wants
>>> [ [int(v)] for v in d.values() ]
=> [[0], [-1], [-1], [-1], [0]]
```

**NOTE :** since the `0` in `[-1,0]` is a bit ambigious, have not included it.